# How can I pass data to tinymce in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tinymce, vuetify.js

I have a form with a couple of filed and a tinymce editor. You can add and edit an item/row. When I try to edit a row and load the properties to their place all load just fine except the tinymce's Content.
I want to parse the code inside the editor in a rendered form (source code=>normal form) but I cannot found a way to do so.

I have tried v-model but it doesnt work with tinymce backwards.

```
<v-flex>
    <tinymce id="d1" v-model="message.Content" :rules="empty"></tinymce>
</v-flex>
```

The message list is loaded with:

```
created() {
  Store.dispatch('customers/getMessageById', this.$route.params.id)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue/issues/4.

Comment: I have the same issue